# error C4430 c++ : missing type specifier - int assumed

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm creating win7 logging application with fingerprint machine, fingerprinting machine sdk gives UFScanner.h header file, when i trying to use "UFS_STATUS" in it on my .cpp code
it gives me these errors:

Error   1   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Error    2   error C2086: 'int ufs_res' : redefinition

```
 

    #ifndef _UFSCANNER_H_
    #define _UFSCANNER_H_
    #define __extension__

    #ifdef UFS_EXPORTS
    #define UFS_API __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall
    #else
    #define UFS_API __stdcall
    #endif
    #define UFS_CALLBACK __stdcall

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif


    // Status Definition
    #define UFS_STATUS               int

    // Status Return Values
    #define UFS_OK                  0
    #define UFS_ERROR               -1
    #define UFS_ERR_NO_LICENSE          -101
    #define UFS_ERR_LICENSE_NOT_MATCH       -102
    #define UFS_ERR_LICENSE_EXPIRED         -103
    #define UFS_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED           -111
    #define UFS_ERR_INVALID_PARAMETERS      -112
    ...
```

And the .cpp Code:

```
 

    #include 
    #include 
    #ifndef WIN32_NO_STATUS
    #include 
    #define WIN32_NO_STATUS
    #endif
    #include 
    #include "CSampleCredential.h"
    #include "guid.h"
    #include "windows.h"

    #include "UFScanner.h"
    #define __extension__

    #define TEMPLATE_SIZE 384

    UFS_STATUS ufs_res;
    int nScannerNumber;

    ufs_res = UFS_Init(); //ufs_res gives error : this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a plain assignment statement outside of a function:

```
ufs_res = UFS_Init();
```

You need to combine it with the definition of `ufs_res` like this:

```
UFS_STATUS ufs_res = UFS_Init();
```

Comment: Thank you RichieHindle, I have applied "UFS_STATUS ufs_res = UFS_Init();" and it solved "Error 1 error C4430" but Error 2 is still there...